# Error while extracting data from an HTML file using lxml: cssselect is not recognised

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml

I'm using Python's function BeautifulSoup to parse an HTML file. It's working but it's too slow when it comes to large files. By searching on the Internet I found that lxml was better and faster.

I want to implement the following code but it's not working:

```
import lxml
import lxml.html as lh
root = lxml.html.fromstring(html_data)
links_lxml_res = root.cssselect("a.detailsViewLink")
links_lxml = [link.get("C:/Month01/A7600607_20200324_112123_1.html") for link in links_lxml_res]
links_lxml = list(set(links_lxml))
```

The error pannel displays that `cssselect` is not recognised and when I try to install it using `pip install cssselect` I have the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cssselect (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cssselect
```